# Find the element that appears after a particular element in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How do I find the element that appears directly after a particular element in a numpy array?

In a Python list, I might do something like:

```
lst[lst.index(some_element)+1]
```

Comment: `lst[next(idx + 1 for idx, val in enumerate(lst) if val == some_element)]` for short-circuiting. But it'll fail if it cannot find it, as the other answers here do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the array is one-dimensional you can use

```
arr[np.nonzero(arr == some_element)[0][0] + 1]
```

Some checks should be added to make sure that `some_element` exists in `arr` and that it is not the last element of the array.

Comment: it seems np.nonzero scans the whole array. is there a way to return the next element as soon as one finds it?

Comment: I think you would either need to convert the array into a list (`arr[arr.tolist().index(some_element) + 1]`) or just iterate over it.

Comment: I think ```np.flatnonzero``` can be used instead of the double indexing.

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) returns a tuple with first all the row indices, then all the column indices.

Assuming one-dimensional lst:

```
lst[np.where(lst == some_element)[0][0] + 1]
```

Comment: It still should be `lst[np.where(lst == some_element)[0][0] + 1]` since `np.where` returns a tuple.